# Meaning of the line in simple words - "Wow,it doesn't pay to pisss off the freezer queen. You end up an entree"

Tags: meaning

The line is from a Netflix documentary **Evil Genius**. I am trying to figure out what the person is trying to say in simple words.

Just explain me in simple words what one implies when he says the above line.

Comment: Don't poke the bear.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annoy (piss off) the woman who owns the freezer, you are in danger of being killed, put in a bag, and frozen like a meal (entree).

Comment: Not quite. "Freezer Queen" was a brand of frozen food -- it's applied here to a woman charged with murdering a man and storing the body in a freezer.